# Detect changes on input[type="text"] immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have to detect the change when the value in `input` with the class `inpt` changes. My solution:

I have this input:

```
<input type="text" class="inpt" />
```

I have this check:

```
$('input.inpt').on("input change", function() {
    doStuff();
})
```

When I type something in the input, `doStuff()` executes immediately. When I need to change input's value in javascript, I do:

```
    $('input.inpt').val(value);
    $('input.inpt').change();
```

Is this a good way to do this (because it seems a little bit dirty to use change function like that)? Will it work on all browsers? Thanks.

Comment: `on("input"` will surely not do much...

Comment: you can use `keypress` cant you?

Comment: @hungerpain I think not, because input's value can be changed from some function in javascript.

Comment: onkeydown (Fires when a user is pressing a key), onkeypress (Fires when a user presses a key) onkeyup (Fires when a user releases a key), _onchange (Fires the moment when the value of the element is changed)_

Comment: @Brett: `change` fires for text-`input` (and `textarea`) elements once that element has lost focus/been blurred. Not immediately.

Comment: @DavidThomas Good note, I don't typically use change over keypress

Comment: @lonesomeday What's your point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `.change()` is just a shortcut for `.trigger('change')`, i.e. you're triggering the change event. That seems like a perfectly acceptable thing to do.

Comment: Actually, `This method is a shortcut for .on('change', handler) in the first two variations, and .trigger('change') in the third.` But I do completely agree :-D

Answer (score 1):

As stated by another answer, calling change for a programmatic change shouldn't seem like a hack of any sort, and in fact may be the best and only way to do so.

```
var oInpt = $('input.inpt')
oInpt.on("change", function(oEvent) { }); 

function changeValue(sStr)
{
    oInpt.val(sStr);
    oInpt.trigger("change"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think doing it this way is not any wrong, but I prefer to write a function to handle this two dependent tasks something like:

```
function setInputValue(inputElement, value)
{
    $(inputElement).val(value);
    doStuff();
}
```